# A very obscure question: Origin of The Wolfman's (Siodmak) hometown name

Tags: the-wolf-man-1941, frankenstein-meets-the-wolfman

It is Visaria or Vasaria (I don't think we ever see it spelled in the movie like on a sign "Welcome to Visaria".) I think the town makes an appearance in more than one movie.

Now here's the deal: Curt Siodmak lived near the real-life town of Visalia in his retirement and I am guessing it is almost 100% that in the 1940s he already knew about Visalia and so this inspired the fictional town's name.

What I am looking for is something definite, not IMDB or something probably copied from IMDB, about this. If Siodmak gave an interview or wrote an autobio where this is discussed.

I would be just amazed if anyone has information on this.

Vasaria/Visaria is also mentioned in the profound and moving Frankenstein Meets the Wolfman -- I am not sure if the town is mentioned in any other film.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently not. In "Siodmak's Brain" in [*Bride of the Gorilla*](https://books.google.com/books?id=S86GDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT313&lpg=PT313&dq=siodmak%20visalia&source=bl&ots=tQ3DTMXqDF&sig=ACfU3U2oyh9OEcSsBMvDthF4ooxE2uN6-g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwia55rq3bvmAhWVW80KHQX_AYQQ6AEwAXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=siodmak%20visalia&f=false), Scott McQueen wrote:

> Curt [Siodmak] and his wife Henrietta had stumbled on Three Rivers
>   [near Visalia] in the late 1950s while searching for a rustic home for
>   Henrietta's fickle mother. On sighting Three Rivers, Henrietta made up
>   her mind. Just as she had moved them out of Nazi Germany and harm's
>   way in 1933, she determined that they would decamp Hollywood for the
>   Sierras. Curt was adamant that he would not Hollywood. His work was
>   there. Henrietta knew better and smiled. They had known no other home
>   since.

So Siodmak had his first acquaintance with Visalia in the 1950s, too late to act as inspiration for *The Wolf Man* (1941). It's a pity, because I was hoping there was a connection.

Comment: how can you remotely conclude that?

Comment: To expand: How can you conclude they had never seen Visalia on a map or driven past the town while driving between Hollywood and San Francisco? It would be so amazing )and what I would prefer) is that they discovered a town named after the fictional town *after* moving to Three Rivers. Like they needed groceries and drove to the near one. "OMG, honey, look what this town is called!  Can you believe it??" If Siodmak had written Wolfman when living in Europe, that would be something, even if he threw darts at a map. But I think the mundane explanation is the likely one.

Comment: It's possible that the Siodmaks previously knew of Visalia as a place on the map, or even that they vacationed there, but where's the evidence? McQueen noted the similarity of names in the first sentence of his article: "One might joke about finding the writer of _Frankenstein Meets the Wolf Man_ living near ... Visaria, ... but I did not expect to pass through its homophonic sister city on my way to meet their author, Curt Siodmak." McQueen interviewed Siodmak and learned how he found his home in the 50s. I think that McQueen had the same idea you did but was disappointed by Siodmak's answer.

Comment: And sure, if the Siodmaks had discovered the real Visalia 15 years or so after _Wolf Man_, they would probably have been delighted by the similarity. But your original post asks whether Visalia inspired Visaria.

Comment: Also, the similarity grew with time. In _Ghost of Frankenstein_ (1942) and _Frankenstein Meets the Wolf Man_, (1943), it was spelled [Vasaria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasaria), but in _House of Frankenstein_ (1944) and _House of Dracula_ (1945), it was spelled Visaria.

Comment: which was still before according to u they could have been aware of the california town.

Comment: The name is similar in form to the Latinized versions of some other central European place names: Bavaria, Moravia, Moldavia, Masovia, Varsavia, Revalia, Basilia. Siodmak could have drawn inspiration from European maps.

Comment: Well, if you are right, that is amazing but that the name got closer to Visalia prior to 1950 really undermines the coincidence idea. But if it is in fact a coincidence, this is right up there with Swift predicting two Martian moons -- writer accidentally moves to within 10 miles of town whose name he made up for a movie.